# What do these messages mean when method was called incorrectly in Python

Tags: python, methods

```
  2 import argparse
  3 
  4 baseline = {'music': 'bach', 'art': 'rembrandt'}
  5 myfault = baseline.copy
  6 print (myfault)
  7 
  8 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  9 myfault = parser.add_argument
 10 print(myfault)
```

This results in the following messages:

```
<built-in method copy of dict object at 0x7ff5c61f75a0>
<bound method _ActionsContainer.add_argument of ArgumentParser(prog...
```

I have been stumped a few times with these typos, where I dropped the parens,  and the resulting messages.

From my understanding myfault is a pointer to the *method* *instance*? And it is printing what it is pointing to?

What would be use of this syntax?

Comment: Printing it isn’t much use but making a dictionary of functions to call later can be very useful

Comment: That method wasn't called incorrectly. It wasn't called at all. The result is a method object, comparable to a function pointer in C++. What you get when printing is a description of the method object: the name (`add_argument`) and the class it belongs to (`ArgumentParser`). The use is that you can read it as a developer.

Comment: if you use it with `print()` then it prints information about this  function - but more useful is that you can send it as argument to other function - and some functions can use this. ie you can send function to `sort()`, `max()`, `min()` and `dataframe.apply()` (in `pandas`), or assign to button in `GUI`